# How to use pattern matching without switch case in javascript (in functional programming way)

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, switch-statement, pattern-matching

I've been reading the clean code book which ask for eliminate using switch case, So I wanted to implement it in JavaScript, and I wanted to use it in functional programming way, so I decided to use pattern matching.

I have the code below, that I want to omit the switch case, how can I do it, not using the polymorphism.

```
function calculateSalary(role) {
    switch (true) {
      case /CTO/.test(role):
        return getCTOSallary();
      case /CEO/.test(role):
        return getCEOSallary();
      case /engineer/.test(role):
        return getEngineeringSallary();
      default:
        return getGeneralSallary();
    }
}
```

Comment: Pattern matching is only remotely related to regular expressions. Anyway, both concepts are based on the idea to unify two terms instead of relying on equality. Javascript doesn't include pattern matching. You might develope a unification algorithm for native types but it would be quite inefficient and probably still awkward to use.

Comment: Btw, advising to avoid `switch` statements in general is nonsensical.

Comment: You can somewhat fake patter matching for custom data type, like [daggy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/daggy) does. But that trick only works on tagged constructors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do so would be to use [dynamic dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch).

```js
const Engineer = (name, bonus) => ({ constructor: Engineer, name, bonus });

Engineer.calculateSalary = engineer => 20 + engineer.bonus;

const Employee = (name, bonus) => ({ constructor: Employee, name, bonus });

Employee.calculateSalary = employee => 10 + employee.bonus;

const calculateSalary = role => role.constructor.calculateSalary(role);

console.log("John's salary is", calculateSalary(Engineer("John", 10))); // 30
console.log("Mary's salary is", calculateSalary(Employee("Mary", 10))); // 20
```

Note that we could have used classes for dynamic dispatch too. However, I wanted to show that it's possible to have dynamic dispatch without using classes, using a purely functional style of programming.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer: I am the author of the library mentioned in this answer.**

---

I like the way it is done in Clojure with [multimethods](https://clojure.org/reference/multimethods):

> A Clojure multimethod is a combination of a dispatching function, and one or more methods.

1. A dispatching function takes parameter(s) and return a value
2. The dispatched value is used to determine which method to call

The library [@customcommander/multifun](https://github.com/customcommander/multifun) is an attempt at bringing multimethods to JavaScript.

**You first need a *dispatching function***

This will be `getRole`. It returns the part you're interested in or `null` if the role is unknown:

```js
const getRole = role => {
  const match = role.match(/(cto|ceo|engineer)/i);
  return match ? match[1].toLowerCase() : null;
};
```

**Then you'll need a series of value/function pairs**

- `'cto'`, `getCTOSalary`
- `'ceo'`, `getCEOSalary`
- ...

**Finally you need a function when there are no matches**

This will be the `getGeneralSalary` function.

**How does it work?**

- `getRole` is the dispatching function, it is applied to the parameters and returns a value
- The dispatched value is compared with the value in each `value/function` pair.
- If there's a match, the function is applied to the parameters
- The function `getGeneralSalary` is applied to the parameters when there are no matches.

---

```js
const multifun = require("@customcommander/multifun");

const getCTOSalary = (_, {bonus = 0}) => 10 + bonus;
const getCEOSalary = (_, {bonus = 0}) => 20 + bonus;
const getEngineeringSalary = (_, {bonus = 0}) => 30 + bonus;
const getGeneralSalary = (_, {bonus = 0}) => 40 + bonus;

const getRole = role => {
    const match = role.match(/(cto|ceo|engineer)/i);
    return match ? match[1].toLowerCase() : null;
};

const calculateSalary =
    multifun
        (   getRole
        ,   'cto', getCTOSalary
        ,   'ceo', getCEOSalary
        ,   'engineer', getEngineeringSalary
        ,   getGeneralSalary
        );

calculateSalary('Chief Technology Officer (CTO)', {bonus: 1}); //=> 11
calculateSalary('Chief Executive Officer (CEO)', {bonus: 2});  //=> 22
calculateSalary('Senior Software Engineer', {bonus: 3});       //=> 33
calculateSalary('random title', {bonus: 4});                   //=> 44
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```js
function test(str) {
   let tests = [/xyz/, /test/, /ing/];
   if(tests.some(patt => patt.test(str))) {
      console.log("Match found");
   }else {
      console.log("No match found");
   }
}

test("testing");
```

Comment: actually this is an example the result can be different functions, like calculate sallary based on different role in the company, the role became the pattern and based on that chose different functions